# How to extract all matches of a group

Tags: regex, regex-group

Hope someone could help me with my problem. I am trying to use same pattern for capturing same group in a range of text for all values fields.

I try to capture every "value" only related for attribute_2 from the html.
This is my approcah:
    https://regex101.com/r/z5T20g/2

```
<select id="product_attribute_1">
  <option value="1">2.2 GHz</option>
  <option value="2">2.5 GHz</option>
</select>
<select id="product_attribute_2">
  <option value="3">2GB</option>
  <option value="4">4GB</option>
  <option value="5">8GB</option>
</select>

product_attribute_2[\s\S]*"(\d+)"[\s\S]*select> ---this show last match (5)
product_attribute_2[\s\S]*?"(\d+)"[\s\S]*select> --this first (3)
```

How can I extract all values (3,4,5)? There is could be different amount of values. Help please )

P.S. I am not trying to parse html with regex. This values is used in Gatling script.
I was using this example for collecting unique attributes. Think in my case I can use something like this.

```
\b(product_attribute_\d)(?![\s\S]*?\b\1)
```

I use regex for extracting values from response body in Gatling tool (Scala).
This will save all values to List.
 [image]

Make it through css-selector

```
select[id='product_attribute_2'] [value]
```

Comment: You might try using the dom or a domparser instead.

Comment: why are you using a regex while this can be accomplished by using plain javascript

Comment: This is for performance test scripts. But you give me an idea to use css parser instead

Comment: why can't you use the regular dom methods ?

Comment: I don't know if I can use it inside framework (domain specific language). Think regexp would be easiest and less resource consuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have to apply a regular expression for this problem, we can likely start with this simple expression:

```
.*product_attribute_2.*?|option value="(\d+)"|<\/select>.*
```

on `s` mode:

#### [Demo on S Mode](https://regex101.com/r/GpBqT5/1)

or with this expression:

```
[\s\S]*product_attribute_2|option value="(\d+)"|<\/select>[\s\S]*
```

on `m` mode:

#### [Demo on M Mode](https://regex101.com/r/UdtzmH/1)

```js
const regex = /.*product_attribute_2.*?|option value="(\d+)"|<\/select>.*/gs;
const str = `<select id="product_attribute_1">
  <option value="1">2.2 GHz</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="2">2.5 GHz</option>
</select>
<select id="product_attribute_2">
  <option value="3">2GB</option>
  <option value="4">4GB</option>
  <option value="5">8GB</option>
</select>`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Almost that I needed, but it also takes value from "product_attribute_1" https://regex101.com/r/z5T20g/3

Comment: Thanks. It's work for me. [\s\S]*product_attribute_2|option value="(\d+)"|<\/select>[\s\S]*

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the values using vanilla JavaScript as follows:

```js
const options = Array.from(document.querySelector('#product_attribute_2').children);
const values = options.map(x => Number(x.getAttribute('value')));
console.log(values);
```

```html
<select id="product_attribute_1">
  <option value="1">2.2 GHz</option>
  <option value="2">2.5 GHz</option>
</select>
<select id="product_attribute_2">
  <option value="3">2GB</option>
  <option value="4">4GB</option>
  <option value="5">8GB</option>
</select>
```